# Clarification of Strongloop Subscription Pricing CPU versus Node Processes

Tags: subscription, strongloop

Trying to figure out if Strongloop support is priced by CPU/VCPU or by the number Node.js processes? 
Strongloop site, https://strongloop.com/node-js/subscription-plans/  says 
"Subscriptions are sized by number of Node.js application processes/instances, equivalent to the number of CPUs/VCPUs used."
But I can have multiple Node processes on 1 CPU.  So if I had 6 Node processes being supported by 4 physical CPUs how many "processes" do I need to buy for the support plans?

Comment: Seems to be off topic.

Comment: Please send us an email sales@strongloop.com. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

StongLoop subscription plans do not take the number of CPUs into account, only Processes.  You can have as many or as few CPUs as you would like; the number of processes will determine the appropriate subscription plan.

Please let me know if you would like to jump on a quick call to discuss your use case in further detail.